# Disable Flex runtime binding warnings

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, flex3

I am taking XML-type variables in a model and binding with component properties in ActionScript code.  It's perfectly fine if it's unable to bind the child nodes or other sibling properties of the XML itself and I don't want Eclipse to display these runtime warnings!

I did suppress warnings in Flex compiler using "-show-binding-warnings=false", but that does not seem to be working for runtime binding warnings.

> warning: unable to bind to property <'some node name'> on class 'XML' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)

Comment: In some cases you might be able to work-around this behaviour [by defining custom events that the bindings should react to](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showpost.php3?p=1021177&postcount=5), so that it doesn't rely on being able to automatically detect changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-show-binding-warnings=false` option is only for **compile time** binding warnings, it won't affect **runtime** warnings.

In order to change this behaviour it would be necessary to edit the framework itself.

[This was reported to Adobe and they considered extending it to also cover the runtime warnings](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-22244), but the latest update (in December 2010) was:

> Closing as deferred.
>   We will reconsider this in a future release of the Flex SDK.